# Toolstrip Accelerator Text

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

I am trying to get the text of a ToolStripMenuItem as if it has been rendered for drawing.

If I have this:

```
var ts = new ToolStripMenuItem("&New File...");
```

I want to get `"New File..."`, and there does not seem to be a property to get this information.

I had a look through the `TextRenderer` and `ToolStripRenderer` classes in Reflector, and eventually found that it passes the string to an unmanaged function that renders the text to a graphics object.

Does any one know of a built in way of getting the rendered string, or should i just roll my own that handles the `&` (and `&&` etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to remove the '&' characters? Can't you just do something like:

```
ts.Text.Replace("&", string.Empty);
```

Comment: No `&New` would underline the N, so your code would work for that, however if a menu item has this `Health && Safety` it would render to `Health & Safety`.  Like i said i can write a method, i was hoping there was a framework method for it.